# Instantiate database connection in scrapy middleware and access it in other modules

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy, web-crawler

I have couple of different spiders in a project that share the same database, I've got different item classes so I can deal with them properly in the Pipeline and send them to the desired destination. In my first spider, the database is instantiated  in the pipeline like this:

```
def __init__(self, database, user, password, host, port):
    self.database = database
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    db_settings = crawler.settings.getdict("DB_SETTINGS")
    if not db_settings:
        raise NotConfigured
    db = db_settings['database']
    user = db_settings['user']
    password = db_settings['password']
    host = db_settings['host']
    port = db_settings['port']
    return cls(db, user, password, host, port)

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(database=self.database, user=self.user, password=self.password,
                                       host=self.host, port=self.port)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.cursor_close = self.cursor.close()
    self.connection_close = self.connection.close()
```

which works fine, however for my second spider, I need to access some data from the database in the spider itself so I could start crawling and then send items to the pipeline to save them in the database.
I could instantiate the database in the spider using the same code and stop doing it in the pipeline, but there are multiple spiders and I don't want to repeat this process over and over. I was wondering how to instantiate database connection in the middleware and access it both in the spider and in the pipeline. I think I can use the same code above to start the database bud I don't know how to tweak it to access the cursor and the connection in the spider and the pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i made it work, you could do it in the middleware like this:

```
## MiddleWare

class DBMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, db_settings):
        self.db_setting = db_settings

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        db_settings = crawler.settings.getdict("DB_SETTINGS")
        if not db_settings:  # if we don't define db config in settings
            raise NotConfigured

        s = cls(db_settings)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return s

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.connection = psycopg2.connect(database=self.db_setting['database'],
                                           user=self.db_setting['user'],
                                           password=self.db_setting['password'],
                                           host=self.db_setting['host'],
                                           port=self.db_setting['port'])


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.connection.close()
```

then you could add this to the spider to access the connection that was just created

```
## Spider
class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'main_spider'
    start_urls = ['www.example.com']

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return s 

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        pass

    def parse(self, response):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM companies"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for element in result:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=Item_profile(), selector=element)
            loader.add_value('name', element[0])
            items = loader.load_item()
            yield items

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        pass
```

this works fine if you just want to have access to the db connection in the spider pars method, but what i needed was to open the connection before the parse method so i could retrieve the links from the db and crwal each of them individually, so i needed the the connection in the ##Spider spider_opened() method, but the sequence  of methods activating is like this:

```
1: #Spider __init__()
2: #Spider spider_opened()
3: #Middleware spider_opened() -->> connection is  created here
4: #Spider parse()
5: #Spider spider_closed()
6: #Middleware spider_closed()
```

and that's logical since according to the [Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow) the main function of [Middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#spider-middleware) is to sit between the engine and the spider, what we need is a module that instantiates at scrapy startup, and that would be an [Extension](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#extensions). So i created a file named `extentions.py` at root directory alongside middleware, pipelines, etc. and added the same code as the one in the middleware:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
import psycopg2


class DBExtension(object):
    def __init__(self, db_settings):
        self.db_setting = db_settings
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        db_settings = crawler.settings.getdict("DB_SETTINGS")
        if not db_settings:
            raise NotConfigured
        s = cls(db_settings)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return (s)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.connection = psycopg2.connect(database=self.db_setting['database'],
                                           user=self.db_setting['user'],
                                           password=self.db_setting['password'],
                                           host=self.db_setting['host'],
                                           port=self.db_setting['port'])


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.connection.close()
```

then i activated this extension in the `settings.py`

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'ProjectName.extensions.DBExtension': 400
}
```

and now you have access to this connection in #Spider spider_opened() method with `self.connection` and can load information from the database before crawling begins.
I don't know if there is a more optimal way to  get around this, but for now that'll do the job for me.